# AttributeError - module is not available in threading.Thread

Tags: python, django

In Django I wrote a custom command, called update.
This command is continously called by a shell script and updates some values in the database. The updates are done in threads. I put the class doing all-threading related things in the same module as the custom command.

On my production server, when I try to run that shell script, I get an error when I try to access my models:

```
antennas = Antenna.objects.all()
```

The error is:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'objects'
```

As you can see, however, I did import app.models.Antenna in that file. 
So to me, it seems as if the reference to the whole site is somehow "lost" inside the threading class.

#### site/app/management/commands/update.py

(I tried to remove all non-essential code here, as it would clutter everything, but I left the imports intact)

```
from django.core.management.base import NoArgsCommand, CommandError
```

from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from decimal import *
from django.conf import settings
from _geo import *

import random, time, sys, traceback, threading, Queue
from django.db import IntegrityError, connection

from app.models import Bike, Antenna

class Command(NoArgsCommand):
  def handle_noargs(self, **options):
    queue = Queue.Queue()
    threadnum = 2
    for bike in Bike.objects.filter(state__idle = False):
      queue.put(bike)
    for i in range(threadnum):
      u = UpdateThread(queue)
      u.setDaemon(True)
      u.start()
    queue.join()
    return

class UpdateThread(threading.Thread):
  def **init**(self, queue):
    threading.Thread.**init**(self)
    self.queue = queue

def run(self):
    antennas = Antenna.objects.all()
    while not self.queue.empty():
      try:
        [...]
      except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
      finally:
        self.queue.task_done()

When I try to

```
from app.models import Antenna
```

inside the UpdateThread-class I get an error:

```
ImportError: No module named app.models
```

The site runs great on a webserver. No model-related problems there, only when I do anything inside a thread - all app.models-imports are failing.
Additionally, it seems to me as exactly the **same** configuration (I'm using git) **does** run on another machine, which runs the same operating system (debian wheezy, python 2.7.3rc2 & django 1.4.2).

Very probably I'm missing something obvious about threading here but I'm stuck for far too long now. Your help would be very much appreciated!

PS: I did check for circular imports - and those shouldn't happen anyway, as I can use my models in the other (management-)class, right?

Comment: you are sure the Antenna class is defined in app/models.py and it's all there in the folder? You don't want to be doing too much for a silly mistake!

Comment: @inLoveWithPython yes, as I said - when running with manage.py runserver everything works... but I'll have a very close look again.

Comment: And make sure your Django versions are in sync. If your are using Virtualenv or anything similar, make sure you get the right Django version here.